# how to findout full path of an object in actionscipt3

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs5

How to find out targetpath of a movieclip or a textfield.??
i need to get full path of a movieclip like `Object(root).moviclip1.movieclip2.textfield`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am fairly sure there is no one property or method that can give you this. You could loop through the displaylist tree, searching for your target. But this might be a large loop depending on how many graphics you have

Answer (score 1):

**did u mean like this?**

```
addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, targetMC);
    function targetMC(ev:Event):void
    {
        var curinstance = ev.target.valueOf();//object
        var targ:Object = curinstance.parent;
        var path= curinstance;
        do
        {
            if (targ is Stage)
            {
                path = targ + "." + path;
            }
            else
            {
                path = targ + "." + path;
            }

            targ = targ.parent;
        }

    trace(path);

    }
```

Comment: @Roy yes i forgot.Did u getting path?Can u give properties/methods to that object??

Comment: addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, targetMC);
function targetMC(ev:Event):void
{
 var curinstance = ev.target.valueOf();//object
 var targ:Object = curinstance.parent;
 var path = curinstance;
 do
 {
  if (targ is Stage)
  {
   path = targ + "." + path;
  }
  else
  {
   path = targ + "." + path;
  }

  targ = targ.parent;
 } while (targ!=null);
 
 //this[path].x = 100;
 trace(path);

}
this["teg5"].appendText("this is sting to obj");

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what you're looking for, and I wrote a little function that accomplishes that. It's pretty ugly but should do the trick.

```
function getChildFromPath(base:DisplayObjectContainer, path:String):DisplayObject
{
    var pathAsArr:Array = path.split(".");
    if (pathAsArr.length)
    {
        var newBase:DisplayObjectContainer = base.getChildByName(pathAsArr.shift() as String) as DisplayObjectContainer;
        if (newBase)
            return getChildFromPath(newBase, pathAsArr.join("."));
        else
            return null;
    }
    return base;
}
```

You give it the start location of a path to look in (this, or stage, depending where you end you're drilling for the path), and the path in string.

So for example, suppose I have an mc named "a" on this, and inside "a" there's an mc named "b", you couldn't get it with this["a.b"], but rather with this["a"]["b"].
Using this function, you can do:

```
var path:String = "a.b";
var mc:DisplayObject = getChildFromPath(this, path);
```

I didn't check it with too many types of inputs, so I'm not sure it won't break or loop forever in some circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be what you want to hear, but it seems you are trying a Actionscript 2 style of doing things.

You may wish to read more into OOP (Object Orientated Programming).
It will seem very Alien and like its actually working against you but when projects get bigger it helps a great deal.

the names of movieclips are no longer the property names of the parent. I fear if you was to do what I think u are trying to do get the property names to traverse the movieclip tree, it would not work, you would see something like

stage.instance2.instance15.instance45.instance90;

which as you can guess would not help much.

Comment: Actually am dealing with keyboard interaction so that there are so many forms enclosing textfields.When i click or focus on any of/every textfield keyboard appears and with that keyboard i can type.But the problem is that when i click on one text field i would like to get the targtpath of that textfield.even when i changes the focus to another textfield i have to type on that textfield too.There are lots of text fields in the form.Here is the code to get the targetpath/display object path in a string.. i need to convert this path to object and i want to give properties to that object.

Comment: Ahh, I did something like this a while ago..

What I did was extended flash.text.TextField with a "my.text.TextField" and Had a Static Singleton class for the KeyboardStatic, and on focus/click it would send a direct reference to the KeyboardStatic which would activate the keyboard and the keyboard with start sending keys to that..

If you cannot/donot wish to make a extended TextField class, maybe having a public static function on the KeyboardStatic which would register the keyboard and add the click/focus events to it but this would involve you going into ur code/movieclips and doing

Comment: KeyboardStatic.register(_tfTextField1);
KeyboardStatic.register(_tfTextField2);